# Python minimize_scalar calculate polynomial minimum value is not correct

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to use minimize_scalar to calculate the minimum and maximum of 1d polynomial.

The polynomial is x^{6}-2x^{5}-26x^{4}+28x^{3}+145x^{2}-26x-80

The code is showing below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import *
ppar = np.array([1, -2, -26, 28, 145, -26, -80])
p = np.poly1d(ppar)
print p

maximum = minimize_scalar(-p, bounds=(-3.978, 3.068), method = 'bounded')
print "(-3.978, 3.068)", -maximum.fun
print maximum

minimum = minimize_scalar(p, bounds=(-3.978, 3.068), method = 'bounded')
print "(-3.978, 3.068)", minimum.fun
print minimum
```

The result is

```
   6     5      4      3       2
1 x - 2 x - 26 x + 28 x + 145 x - 26 x - 80
(-3.978, 3.068) 86.0883584933
  status: 0
    nfev: 12
 success: True
     fun: -86.0883584932823
       x: -1.5444720061831096
 message: 'Solution found.'
(-3.978, 3.068) -81.1476243092
  status: 0
    nfev: 11
 success: True
     fun: -81.147624309245643
       x: 0.08767224353999728
 message: 'Solution found.'
```

However, the real solution of the 1d polynomial should be maximum: 264.155 at x=2.176, and minimum -436.947 at x = -3.391

Is anyone know that what's wrong with my code or is there something that I missed?

Thanks for any help comments.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are oscillating, and have several extrema. What you get are simply different ones. Note that a local minimizer finds *a* minimum and if there are several, it reports one of them.

For polynomials, you are best off using specialized minimizers. E.g., differentiate and find the roots of the derivative using the companion matrix approach:

```
In [53]: coef = [-26, 2*145, 3*28, -4*26, -5*2]    # coefficients for the derivative

In [54]: coef = np.asarray(coef, dtype=float)

In [55]: coef /= 6  # make it monic

In [56]: coef
Out[56]: array([ -4.33333333,  48.33333333,  14.        , -17.33333333,  -1.66666667])

In [57]: a = np.diag(np.ones(4), -1)     # build the companion matrix

In [58]: a[:, -1] = -coef
```

Eigenvalues of the companion matrix are roots of the derivative (and vice versa), hence the extrema of the original polynomial:

```
In [61]: np.linalg.eigvals(a)
Out[61]: array([-3.39056572, -1.54447197,  0.08767236,  2.17555358,  4.33847842])

In [62]: pp = np.poly1d([1, -2, -26, 28, 145, -26, -80])   # sanity check

In [63]: pp(np.linalg.eigvals(a))
Out[63]: 
array([-436.94699498,   86.08835849,  -81.14762431,  264.15457395,
       -794.0522912 ])
```

An obligatory word of caution is that polynomials of large degree are best avoided because they are unstable.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is using the [scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html) you can find the local minimum. The details are in [@ev-br answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040189/5510499). However, you could use [global optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#global-optimization) methods to find the global minimum of a function within given bounds. Even in this case you should be prepared that those methods could fail either, due to usage of a local minimizer under the hood. In the next example you can see that [shgo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html#scipy.optimize.shgo) optimizer fails to find a global minimum:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

p = np.poly1d([1, -2, -26, 28, 145, -26, -80])

bounds = [(-3.978, 3.068)]

results = {}

results['shgo'] = optimize.shgo(p, bounds)    
results['DA'] = optimize.dual_annealing(p, bounds)    
results['DE'] = optimize.differential_evolution(p, bounds)

print(results['shgo']['x'], results['DA']['x'], results['DE']['x'])
[0.08767235] [-3.39056566] [-3.39056573]
```